# Rails, Create a Task in multiple environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, task

I actually have few custom rake tasks.
What I want to do is to create a task that will execute itself on two environments when you simply call it.
I mean, when I run this :

`rake initialize_global_settings`

I want this to be executed on development **and** test environment.

Actually I'm constrained doing this :

`rake initialize_global_settings` (This will be executed in development environment by default, I don't really know why)
and then I do this :
`rake initialize_global_settings RAILS_ENV=test`

Is it possible to make a task doing both ?

Here's my task :

```
task :initialize_global_settings => :environment do
  puts "Generating all global settings parameters..."
  parameters = ["few", "parameters", "here"]

  parameters.each do |param|
    glob_set = GlobalSetting.new(:field_name => param,
                                  :field_value => "")
    if glob_set.save
      puts "#{param} created"
    else
      puts "#{param} already exist"
    end
  end

  puts "done."
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution doing this :

```
task :initialize_global_settings => :environment do
   puts "Generating all global settings parameters..."
   parameters = ["few", "parameters", "here"]
   environments = ['development', 'test']

   environments.each do |environment|
     Rails.env = environment
     puts "\nRunning Task in "+environment+" environment \n\n"
     parameters.each do |param|
       glob_set = GlobalSetting.new(:field_name => param,
                                     :field_value => "")
       if glob_set.save
         puts "#{param} created"
       else
         puts "#{param} already exist"
       end
     end
     puts "\nParameters have been set"
    end
 end
```

It works but I've got a conflict between same variables set in test and development environment and I don't know why.